# Host is up. All 1000 scanned ports on ***.***.**.* are in ignored states. Not shown: 1000 filtered tcp ports (no-response)

Tags: networking, kali-linux, nmap

I am trying to scan an ip address using nmap using the command:

```
sudo nmap -A ***.***.*.*
```

and I get this as a result

```
Host is up.
All 1000 scanned ports on ***.***.**.* are in ignored states.
Not shown: 1000 filtered tcp ports (no-response)
```

I don't know what is really the problem, thank you in advance for your help

Comment: This host have no services exposed to this IP. Or firewall which filter (at least) all 1000 ports for your IP.

Comment: this is not indicative of a particular problem, as it stands. if you want to tell if nmap is working properly, you may want to consider a more comphrensive scan, so you get some other results beyond just the services scan.